# Ballerina - Swan Lake Beta 1 - How to call function in module?

Tags: beta, ballerina

I am using the ballerina Swan Lake beta
bal dist list => `* [slbeta1] Beta 1`

I have a package "ack" created by `bal new ack`
I have a module in that package "phooey",created by `bal add phooey`

in ack - main.bal

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    io:println(sayWhat());
}
```

in module phooey - phooey.bal

```
public function sayWhat() returns string{
    return "Phooey!";
}
```

Ballerina.toml is the default:

```
[build-options]
observabilityIncluded = true
```

I cannot get this package to compile. The call to `sayWhat()` is not visible

```
ERROR [main.bal:(4:16,4:25)] undefined function 'sayWhat'
error: compilation contains errors
```

Despite reading the documentation multiple times, trying many different ways, I cannot find a way to make the module code visible to the default module/package code. I've tried multiple ways to make it visible via different formats of `import` statements. They don't complile. I have tried referencing the function via module reference and package.module reference. None compile.

How do I make the module code visible to the default module/package code?

**Update**: Have tried Sameera's suggestion below. It does not work. The result is:

```
ERROR [main.bal:(2:1,2:15)] cannot resolve module 'phooey'
ERROR [main.bal:(5:16,5:25)] undefined function 'sayWhat'
error: compilation contains errors
```

**Update2**: What DOES work is:

```
import ack.phooey;
```

Though I'm having a challenge in my actual project which has functions in other than the `phooey.bal` equivalent.

**Update3** This seems to create a package based on my username. Edited Ballerina.toml to:

```
[package]
org = "doh"
name = "ack"
version = "0.1.0"

[build-options]
observabilityIncluded = true
```

**As requested** - project structure

```
blah/blah/ack
│   .gitignore
│   Ballerina.toml
│   main.bal
│
├───modules
│   └───phooey
│           phooey.bal
│
└───target
```

Answer (score 1):

To refer to symbols in another module, you need to use the module prefix. Refer to the following links for more details.
https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/programs-and-modules
https://ballerina.io/learn/user-guide/ballerina-packages/dependencies/

Try updating your `main.bal` in as follows.

```
import ballerina/io;
// By default last part of the module name becomes to prefix
// Since this module is in the same package, you don't have to use the organization name.
import ack.phooey;

public function main() {
    io:println(phooey:sayWhat());
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the directory layout of your package?

Comment: Let me update the answer by adding the package name